# Change date format with ReportBuilder

Tags: sql, time, reportbuilder, scada

Time of occurrence says `03/24/2021` but I want it to be `24/03/2021`…
I have changed it to regional `*31/12/00 13.00.00` time setting, it's not working.

I have been using report builder for creating report for Scada.

[Please have a look at this attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQVuB.png)

Comment: Which dbms? Which report tool?

Comment: Gosh.  Use ISO standard formats . . . 2021-03-24.  Then you won't have to figure out what 10/1/2024 means.

Comment: On same report Batch start time show 24/03/2021 on header and on table where i hv used "Fields!TIMECOMES.Value" expression it shows 03/24/2021.

Comment: microsoft sql server report builder 2.0